# Django haystack: Boosting search results if the searchterm appears in a specific field

Tags: django, search, django-haystack

I'm using django-haystack for searching on my site. 
My problem is, I would like to have search results on top if the search term was found in a specific field.
Let's say I search for blog-entries, then I would like to show those results on top where the search term was found in the title field.

I read the haystack documentation about field-boosting but i don't understand how it should work.

Answer (score 5):

You can either:

Amend your search index file e.g.

```
class BlogEntryIndex(SearchIndex):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    title = CharField(model_attr='title', boost=1.125)
```

**NOTE: As pointed out in the comments the below would only boost the term title not the field, use the above.**

or you can pass the boost to your SearchQuerySet e.g in your haystack urls file.

```
sqs = SearchQuerySet().boost('title', 1.125)

urlpatterns = patterns('haystack.views',
    url(r'^$', SearchView(searchqueryset=sqs), name='haystack_search'),
)
```

Comment: Hello again, Thanks for the quick response! I know these two variants from the documentation and the first variant looks interesting but do i have to do something else to make it work? I already tried it but it seems to change nothing at all... The second variant doesn't help me much because it only boosts a searchterm not a field, at least thats how i understand it.

Comment: Which search backend are you using?

Comment: strange i've got similar setup with whoosh that seems to be working fine, are you setting the order_by to 'score'? although i think that might be the default??

Comment: Tried it, but that wasn't the problem either... Thanks for your untiring help!

Comment: @JamesO: doesn't SearchQuerySet().boost('title', 1.5) perform a boost when the _term_ 'title' is searched for... not the _field_ 'title'?

Comment: @ForeverLearnNeverMaster - yes i think so, that's what scherlock pointed out in his first comment, apologies i should have edited the answer.